# Обработка полей даты разных форматов и сохранение в бд

Tags: java, json, unixtimestamp, база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста как поступить в данном случае: приходит модель json где встречаются некоторые поля с датой или временем записанные в разных форматах, я не до конца понимаю к чему мне нужно преобразовать их в модели, чтобы потом можно было бы записать в базу данных и производить какие-либо манипуляции. К примеру стандартный формат даты вида: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss преобразовав к Date можно записать в бд в виде long UTC timestamp и при извлечении даты как то преобразовывать ей к местному времени, но как поступить например только с yyyy-MM-dd или только с hh:mm:ss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от задачи, которая перед вами стоит. Подозреваю, что формат даты не меняется случайно для одного и того же поля. Поэтому для каждого из них следует использовать подходящий формат.

Для даты(полной, либо нет) использовать timestamp, для времени я бы выбрал `integer=hours*60*60+minutes*60+seconds`

при этом неполная дата сохранится как `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00`

Answer (score -1):

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy");
public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER_2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER_2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm");
public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER_3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm dd.MM.yyyy");

public static String timeFormat(final TemporalAccessor time)
{
    return TIME_FORMATTER.format(time);
}

public static String dateFormat(final TemporalAccessor dateTime)
{
    return DATE_FORMATTER_2.format(dateTime);
}

public static String dateFormat(final Instant instant)
{
    final ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    return dateFormat(dateTime);
}

public static String dateTimeFormat(final TemporalAccessor dateTime)
{
    return DATE_TIME_FORMATTER_3.format(dateTime);
}

public static String dateTimeFormat(final Instant instant)
{
    final ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    return dateTimeFormat(dateTime);
}
```

вот стандартный форматер, юзайте на здоровье